# Encountering some bugs regarding the Scanner and an unknown source in my code. No idea how to fix it

Tags: java, methods, java.util.scanner

I'm trying to teach myself some java and this is my code, but these are the errors that i'm getting as soon as i make my first input telling the program which conversion mode to go into. Any help is appreciated

[image: Errors]

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TempConverter {

        public static void cToF(){
        double C=0, F=0, mode= 0;
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter your temperature in Celsius.");
        C = input.nextDouble();
        input.close();
        F = ((double)9/(double)5*C)+32;
        System.out.println("The temperature you entered in Celsius:"+ C);
        System.out.println("Converts to:"+ F + "in Fahrenheit");
        System.out.println("entery any number to switch converters");
        mode = input.nextDouble();
        if (mode< 0 || mode >0){

            ftoC();
        }
    }

    public static void ftoC(){
        double C=0, F=0, mode= 0;
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter your temperature in Fahrenheit.");
        F = input.nextDouble();
        input.close();
        C = (F-32)*((double)5/(double)9);
        System.out.println("The temperature you entered in Fahrenheit:"+ F);
        System.out.println("Converts to:"+ C + "in Celsius");
        System.out.println("entery any number to switch converters");
        mode = input.nextDouble();
        if (mode< 0 || mode >0){

            cToF();
    }
        }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int conv;
        System.out.println("Enter 1 for F to C conversion");
        System.out.println("Enter 2 for C to F conversion");
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        conv = input.nextInt();
        input.close();
        if ( conv == 1) {

            cToF();
        }
        else {

            ftoC();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `1` is not a double, try `1.0` instead

Comment: Tried changing the 1 to a 1.0 in the main method but i'm still getting the same error..

Comment: I seem to have temporarily fixed my problem by removing the input.close;  statements in each method.

Similar problem was found in this thread and it seems to have worked for them too

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26722065/java-util-scanner-throwforunknown-source-why-doesnt-my-code-work?rq=1

Comment: Yeah, probably not a good idea to close the `System.in`

Comment: You apparently found the solution before I finished my answer. Yes, it is a known issue.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your `input.close();`. When `Scanner` is opened for `System.in` (keyboard entry stream), closing the Scanner also closes the **stream** itself.

Technical details:

[`System.in`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html) implements [`Closeable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Closeable.html)

From [`Scanner` docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html):

> When a Scanner is closed, it will close its input source if the source implements the Closeable interface.

**Suggested solution**:

When using `Scanner` to capture keyboard input, open it once in the beginning and never close (or close at the very end of execution).